# gulp watch changed callback fires before watch tasks

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I have this code for watching file changes. 
I expect 'build-dev-mainjs' task to be run first. then `$.livereload.changed` should be run next. But it's the opposite.

```
 // syncronous
gulp.task('build-dev-mainjs', ['jshint', 'clean'], function() {
    console.log('inmaindevjs');
    return gulp.src(['app/client/scripts/*.js',
                'app/client/bower_components/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts'));
});


gulp.watch('app/client/scripts/**/*.js', ['build-dev-mainjs'])
    .on('change', $.livereload.changed);
```

The reason i want this behaviour is, because after each change, build-dev-mainjs task runs which copies the files into dist folder. The server serves the files from dist folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the gulp plugin: `run-sequence`

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
// This will run in this order:
// * build-clean
// * build-scripts and build-styles in parallel
// * build-html
// * Finally call the callback function
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('build-clean',
              ['build-scripts', 'build-styles'],
              'build-html',
              callback);
});
```

This should sort it.

Comment: It didn't specifically solved the watch problem but it solves a similar problem i faced, so no upvote but i accept the answer.